# Cisco Switch Catalyst 3750: "re-include" ip address in DHCP pool

Tags: cisco, switch, dhcp

I know that I can exclude a range of ip addresses from a DHCP servers pool with

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.10
```

but how do I re-include these addresses into the DHCP pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the excluded-address command by negating the existing line of config:

> no ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.3.1 192.168.3.10

Make sure your network statement within the dhcp block of config covers these addresses in terms of the subnet mask it is using and the addresses should get assigned going fwd.